# Problema 8 Reinas tabla de caracteres

Tags: c++, c

estoy haciendo un programa en c/c++ para poder resolver el problema de de las 8 reinas. Mi programa lee un you archivo.txt de 8x8 con el comando `./programa < text1.txt` este esta lleno de ' _ ' que son los espacios en blanco y ' * ' que son la reines, esto es una tabla de caracteres..:

```
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ *
_ _ _ * _ _ _ _
* _ _ _ _ _ _ _
_ _ * _ _ _ _ _
_ _ _ _ _ * _ _
_ * _ _ _ _ _ _
_ _ _ _ _ _ * _
_ _ _ _ * _ _ _
```

(Tengo varios de estos no solo uno). Entonces yo tengo el codigo bool para leer:

```
char c1; char c2;

for (int f = 0; f < SIZE; f++)
{
    for (int c = 0; c < SIZE; c++)
    {
        Saltar_Blancs ();
        scanf ("%c", &c1);
        if (c1 == '*') {
            c2 = 'Q';
        } else {
                c2 = ' ';
        }
        tabler[f][c] = c2;
    }
}
return true; // Tot correcte
```

El codigo transforma transforma las ' * ' en Q y todo lo otro en espacios en blanco. Después tengo un void para enseñar la tabla

```
    for (int z = 0; z < SIZE; z++){
        printf ("+---");
    }
    printf ("+\n");

    for (int c = 0; c < SIZE; c++)
    {
        printf ("| %c ", tabler[f][c]);
    }
    printf ("|\n");


}
for (int x = 0; x < SIZE; x++){
    printf ("+---");
}
printf ("+\n");
printf ("\n");
```

Este codigo me pone las Q y los espacios en blanco dentro de unos cuadrados que hago a traves de prints.

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| Q |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   | Q |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   | Q |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |   | Q |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   | Q |   | Q |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   | Q |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   | Q |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Mi problema es, yo quiero que por cada archivo.txt diferente que yo le pase al programa él me diga que error tiene, por ejemplo: si tiene 0 reinas, si las reinas se pueden atacar en horizontal o vertical, diagonal tambien y por ultimo decir si el el archivo.txt esta bien y no tiene ningun error

```
void Posicio_Segura (char tabler [SIZE][SIZE])

int f, c;
char r;
char l;

for (f = r; f>= 0; f--)
{
    for (c = l; c>=0; c--)
    {
        if (tabler [f][c] != 'Q')
        {
            printf ("Error: Nombre de reines incorrecte!\n");
        }else if (tabler [f][c] == 'Q')
        {
            printf ("Error: Atac de reines en alguna fila o columna!\n");
        }else{
            printf ("Correcte!\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Este es el codigo que tengo, que printa el (if) cuando las Reinas no tienen ningun error, cuando se atacan en diagonal o cuando no hay ninguna reina en el tablero. Por otro lado me printa el (else if) si las reinas se atacan en horizontal o vertical, esta es la unica condicion que se cumple.

Comment: Si me puedan dar una mano con el problema, algun consejo porque soy principiante, este es mi primer año de programación.

Comment: ¿En [tag:c] o en [tag:c++]? ¿Cuál de los dos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mi recomendación sería que en una primera pasada obtengas paras las 8 reinas sus posiciones como coordenadas, guardándolas digamos en un array de 8x2, es decir:

```
int posQ[8][2];
int nQ=0;//se incrementará cada vez que encuentre una reina

for (int f = 0; f < SIZE; f++)
{
    for (int c = 0; c < SIZE; c++)
    {
       if (tabler [f][c] == 'Q')
       {
        posQ[nQ][0]=f;//posQ es el array para guardar las posiciones
        posQ[nQ][1]=c;
        nQ++;
       }
    }
}
```

Si luego de esto se cuenta menos de 8 reinas, es decir, si `nQ` no ha llegado o se ha pasado de 7, ahí terminaría el programa y se arrojaría el mensaje de reinas insuficientes o algo así. Luego cuando ya tengas las coordenadas de las 8 reinas realizas la verificación de ataques por filas, columnas y diagonales.

Para la verificación de ataques, sugiero obtener las diferencias entre las coordenadas de dos reinas, con esto obtendremos dos valores, una diferencia para las filas `diff` y una diferencia para las columnas `difc`, si `diff=0` significará que las reinas están en una misma fila, por su parte si `difc=0` significará que las reinas están en una misma columna, y por último, si los valores absolutos de `diff` y `difc` son iguales significará que las reinas están en una misma diagonal, entonces el código sugerido seria:

```
//verificación de ataques
    bool pass = true;//cambiará a false si se encuentran reinas atacándose
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < SIZE; j++) {//solo será necesario verificar con las reinas siguientes
            int diff = posQ[j][0] - posQ[i][0];//diferencia de filas
            int difc = posQ[j][1] - posQ[i][1];//diferencia de columnas
            if (diff == 0 || difc == 0 || abs(diff) == abs(difc)) {
                if (diff == 0)
                    printf("Las reinas %i y %i se atacan en la fila\n", i + 1, j + 1);
                else if(difc==0)
                    printf("Las reinas %i y %i se atacan en la columna\n", i + 1, j + 1);
                else
                    printf("Las reinas %i y %i se atacan en diagonal\n", i + 1, j + 1);
                pass = false;
            }
        }
    }
    if(pass)
        printf("La posición actual es una solución!\n");//solo se imprimirá si pass no cambió a false.
```

`i+1` y `j+1` serían, en este caso, las filas de las reinas actuales, contándolas desde arriba, puedes mejorar el código para que por ejemplo, en vez de darte los índices `i+1` y `j+1` que podrían ser un poco ambiguos, te de la posición de la reina en coordenadas del tablero de ajedrez que todo jugador entienda.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu profesionalidad, la verdad es que has hecho demasiado y demasiado bien el problema, no se como agradecerlo. He podido finalizar mi problema sin ninguna error, y por cada archivo.txt que yo le paso al programa me lo interpreta de la forma correcta, me temía que la tablar se tenia que hacer con enteros y no caracteres, pero veo que ese no era el problema. Simplemente muchas gracias. Y perdón por responder tan tarde.